# Ubuntu cloud server : hardware requirements

Tags: server, hardware, cloud, mediaserver, owncloud-server

I Want to get more information about Public cloud hosting (commercial).

Does Ubuntu support it ? And what hardware parts I need to buy with a budget of 12,000 dollars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu can run commercial cloud services without any issues, provided the application(s) offering the cloud service are properly configured.

One such application is OwnCloud which is quite efficient at its work for heavy usage and can be deployed for commercial/private usage.

**Software first:**

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is suggested.
MySQL/MariaDB for database.
apache + php 7 for webserver.
Most recent version of OwnCloud
```

**For hardware requirements :**

The system you will need depends on the number of concurrent users trying to access the server. For following list, I assume you have 100 concurrent users accessing. (*This answer depends on opinion hence, I am giving answer from my personal experience*).

1. 6-10 HDDs (4 or 8 TB each) running in RAID10 configuration
2. CPU - Intel Xeon processor with >8 cores. (Dual CPU system with two processors is also possible for heavy workloads).
3. RAM - 32 GB or higher size ECC(error correcting) RAM is preferred.
4. You don't need GPU.
5. Motherboard - You need a motherboard which should have at least two
   Ethernet ports, and dual socket board if you plan a dual CPU setup.

(Hard disk size depends on your required need.  RAM greater than 32GB and two CPUs on a board are almost essential for commercial setup with heavy workload.)

A few starting points:

`High end server Motherboards:` [Asus](https://www.asus.com/us/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/Commercial-Server-Motherboards-products/), [SuperMicro](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon1333/#2011)

```
CPUs: Select CPU based on CPU socket of the board.
Memory : Choose supported memory based on the motherboard.
```

**Configuration**

Even with very good hardware, poorly configured software will make the server fail. Hence, the tricky part is how well is the components of OwnCloud optimized for workload.

*Some things to consider while setting up :*

- Concurrent connections allowed in `apache`
- `apache` timeout duration should be appropriate.
- Concurrent `php` connections per page served.
- Max size of file transfers  in `php`.
- Max number of database connections.
- Optimization in tables of database may be needed (optimization of InnoDB tables and DB parameters)
- Owncloud - Memory Caching should be used (APC/APCu on Ubuntu is preferred)
- Owncloud - Cache directory location should be on a fast drive(maybe MLC or SLC based SSDs)
- Use SSL for security (necessary for commercial work).

Check these link for details and more:
[OwnCloud- pre setup optimization](https://github.com/owncloud/documentation/wiki/Performance-Tuning-(unofficial)) , 
[OwnCloud server tuning](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/performance_tuning.html).